# How to configure Eclipse to properly load a plugin?

Tags: ros, pluginlib, eclipse

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to use Eclipse to debug the navigation stack (or debug how I am mis-using the stack). I have created an Eclipse project for move_base (make eclipse-project in move_base package), but am unsure how to deal with the plugins that need to be loaded. During initialization of the MoveBase class I get the following error:

```
[rospack] couldn't find package [nav_core]
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'pluginlib::LibraryLoadException'
  what():  rospack could not find the nav_core package containing nav_core::BaseGlobalPlanner
```

I appreciate that many ROS developers use command line tools, but I have enjoyed using Eclipse on simpler projects. Is there an Eclipse project configuration step that I am likely missing to allow loading/debugging of plugins?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9963/how-to-configure-eclipse-to-properly-load-a-plugin?/) by [Bart](https://answers.ros.org/users/286/bart/) on ROS Answers with karma: 856 on 2011-05-15

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bart](https://answers.ros.org/users/286/bart/) on 2011-05-16**:
I'm launching it off a program launcher, but I set up the ROS environment variables in the Launch Configuration Properties/Environment window. It works fine for ROS nodes distributed across multiple computers.

**Comment by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) on 2011-05-15**:
Hi, are you starting eclipse from the command line, to get all your environment variables (ROS_PACKAGE_PATH, etc...). I'm not really sure if that's your problem as I'm not using eclipse myself, but I remember reading something about this a while ago. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Eclipse environment variables needed to define ROS_PACKAGE_PATH. Added this variable and problem solved.

---

Originally posted by [Bart](https://answers.ros.org/users/286/bart/) with karma: 856 on 2011-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3